# How do I print Number of Square Integers between 2 given integers? [ C program]

Tags: c, while-loop

Please tell me what is wrong in my code.
ps- i know about floor and ceiling functions but i came up with this code by myself and would like to know, what should i change.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{ int q,start,end;
  int i,j,k,count=0;
  scanf("%d",&q);
  while(q--)
  {
      for (i=1;i<=q;i++)
      {
          scanf("%d %d",&start,&end);
      }
      for(j=start ;j<=end;j++)
      {
          for(k=1;k*k<=j;k++)
          {
          if(k*k == j)
          count=count+1;
          }
      }
      printf("%d \n",count);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a *very* suboptimal approach. You better calculate "square integers" one by one and compare them to your range. The only tricky part if to determine the first one .

Comment: Is the space after the number in the output really required?

Comment: Take the parameters from the command line instead of reading them from stdin.

Comment: What do YOU think is wrong with your code?  Why do you think you should change something?  Does it produce the wrong results?  You should include these kinds of details in your question.   Describe the expected results vs actual results, and tell us what you do or do not understand about the situation.

Comment: Please add some details on what you are expecting to see as an output and what you are currently observing.

Comment: Explanation:
In simple words, between 3 and 5 there is ONE square integer and TWO square integers between 11 and 26.
Now similarly i have to find total number square integers between START and END.

INPUT 
5 (Test case q)
(67 145)  
(47 69 )  (89 102) (13 58)   
(7 83)    


Expected OUTPUT
4
2
1
4
7

Answer (score 1):

I optimised your code. This should run in O(q*n^(1/2))

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{ int q,start,end;
  int i,j,k,count=0;
  scanf("%d",&q);
  while(q--)
  {
      /* remove extra loop */
      scanf("%d %d",&start,&end);
      /* initialize count */
      count=0;
      for(int j=1 ;j*j<=end;j++)
      {   
      if(j*j>=start && j*j<=end)
      count=count+1;      
      }
      printf("%d \n",count);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Further more, optimization leads to O(q*n^(1/2)):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{ int q,start,end;
  int i,j,k,count=0;
  scanf("%d",&q);
  while(q--)
  {
      /* remove extra loop */
      scanf("%d %d",&start,&end);
      /* initialize count */
      count=floor(sqrt(end)) - ceil(sqrt(start)) + 1;
      
      printf("%d \n",count);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

[Source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-number-perfect-squares-two-given-numbers/)

Comment: `sqrt` is quite expensive operation, so I wouldn't consider it O(q log n) (where this `log` came from anyway?). Also it is not clear to me why it is correct at all (is it?)

Comment: Your first code gives a wrong answer. For example, it will print `0` for input `1 10 17` while `1` is expected.

Comment: Ok, I corrected the code. There is an efficient algorithm, by which you can calculate square root integer in logn. But I don't know whetherdoes C's uses the same. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/square-root-of-an-integer/

Comment: See the answer on [math](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2026702/438129). This is a counting function, so the interval is just the end minus the start. In practice, `sqrt` may use SSE and be even faster.

Answer (score 0):

- You will have to read only one pair, not `q` pairs, for each iteration.
- You have to initialize count` to zero at the beginning of each iteration, not only at the beginning of the program.

```
include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{ int q,start,end;
  int i,j,k,count=0;
  scanf("%d",&q);
  while(q--)
  {
      /* remove extra loop */
      scanf("%d %d",&start,&end);
      /* initialize count */
      count=0;
      for(j=start ;j<=end;j++)
      {
          for(k=1;k*k<=j;k++)
          {
          if(k*k == j)
          count=count+1;
          }
      }
      printf("%d \n",count);
  }
}
```

Also note that you can obtain the count with only one loop like this:

```
      count=0;
      for(j=0 ;j*j<=end;j++)
      {
          if(start <= j*j)
              count=count+1;
      }
```

Comment: Explanation:
In simple words, between 3 and 5 there is ONE square integer and TWO square integers between 11 and 26.
Now similarly i have to find total number square integers between START and END.

INPUT 
5 (Test case q)
(67 145)  
(47 69 )  (89 102) (13 58)   
(7 83)    


Expected OUTPUT
4
2
1
4
7